# Convert SQL query to HQL(join)

Tags: java, hql

How can I convert the following SQL query to HQL:

```
SELECT A.*,B.code,B.name
FROM ATABLE A, BTABLE B
WHERE B.some_id= A.some_id
Order By A.id;
```

I already wrote the following code :

```
CriteriaBuilder criteria = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<A> cq = criteria.createQuery(A.class);
Root<A> from = cq.from(A.class);
cq.select(from);
cq.orderBy(criteria.desc(from.get("id")));
TypedQuery<A> query = em.createQuery(cq);
```

But the code below allows me only to execute the query :

```
select * from A order by id;
```

Can you help me complete my query please?
Thanks

Comment: What is Hibernate doing for you if you need this level of control over SQL?   You should be thinking about it in terms of objects - that's what ORM is about.

Comment: The line FROM ATABLE A, BTABLE B does a join behind the scene, have a look at criteria with join.